Which the correct way to implement an API request
I'm trying to create a request like that, but with ruby.
curl --request POST \
--url '{BASE_URL}/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic {BASIC_CLIENT}' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data grant_type=client_credentials

Im trying like this:
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://api.userede.com.br/redelabs/oauth2/token")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = http.post(
  url,
  { 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' }.to_json,
  { 'Authorization' => "Basic #{CLIENTID}", 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
)

But i'm getting the following error:
{\"error_description\":\"OAuth 2.0 Parameter: grant_type\",\"error\":\"invalid_request\",\"error_uri\":\"https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-5.2\"}

https://jhawthorn.github.io/curl-to-ruby/ might help

You're formatting the request as JSON, but the system is expecting application/x-www-form-urlencoded.
Replace this:
{ 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' }.to_json,

with this:
{ 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' }.to_query,

to conform to the correct payload type.
That may not be the only error, but it is an obvious one.
Props to @max in his answer for the Rails syntax.

That works!! Thank you.
That was my request.body..
{"access_token":"ACCESS_TOKEN","scope":"feature_merchant_statement merchant-statement","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":1439}"
How do I access access_token?
I've tried request.body.access_token / request.body['access_token']

While this one is fairly straightforward, most of the time one would use something like URI#encode_www_form to encode the form data

I get it with
JSON.parse(request.body)
Thank you @PaulProgrammer

Thanks @engineersmnky!  I'm an API/OAuth expert, not a ruby expert.

In Rails you can simply use { grant_type: 'client_credentials' }.to_query to convert the hash to formdata. https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0/classes/Hash.html#method-i-to_query

Use Hash#to_query to convert the hash to FormData pairs instead of JSON:
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

url = URI("https://api.userede.com.br/redelabs/oauth2/token")
http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = http.post(
  url,
  { 'grant_type' => 'client_credentials' }.to_query,
  { 'Authorization' => "Basic #{CLIENTID}", 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
)

